# Adding function to Json Array in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs

I have this JSON object returned from webapi,

```
[{name:John,val1:10,val2:20,val3:0},
{name:Jane,val1:50,val2:200,val3:0}]
```

I store this array in "$scope.dtArray" which is bound to the UI(textboxes) using ng-repeat. before the binding happens I want to assign a function to add values as shown here

```
this.val3 = function() {return Number(this.val1) + Number(this.val2) };
```

for each object in the array. SO when ever the user changes the val1 and val2 text boxes, the value changes for val3 automatically.

Following is the UI markup...

```
<div ng-repeat="cnt in dtArray track by $index">
    <table style="border-style: solid;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="cnt.name">
                <input type="text" ng-model="cnt.val1">
                <input type="text" ng-model="cnt.val2">
                <input type="text" ng-model="cnt.val3()">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

the function is not getting called in change of value in val1 or val2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you have to add the function in your service, e.g. where you assign the json to the dataobject in angular.

Comment: can you share your complete code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below html code instead of your code

```
<div ng-repeat="cnt in dtArray track by $index">
    <table style="border-style: solid;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="cnt.name">
                <input type="text" ng-model="cnt.val1">
                <input type="text" ng-model="cnt.val2">
                <input type="text" ng-init="cnt.val3=val3(this)" ng-model="cnt.val3">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

also your `val3` function should be used by `$scope.functionName()`

like :

```
$scope.val3
```

Try the code below instead of your code

```
$scope.val3 = function(context) {return Number(context.val1) + Number(context.val2) };
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to bind a function to an input `ng-model`, I'm surprised angular even tolerate that (if it does).

Comment: input value could use `ng-value="cnt.val3=val3(this)" ` but why you passed  this, I'm curious to know it

Comment: i did't use `ng-value` in my answer

Comment: That still won't work: val3 is initialized with the correct value but not updated as a user edits val1 and val2.

Answer (score -1):

Do you still want `val3` to be an editable input? You could do that:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="cnt.name">
<input type="text" ng-model="cnt.val1">
<input type="text" ng-model="cnt.val2">
<input type="text" ng-model="cnt.val3">
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.$watch('(cnt.val1 || 0) + (cnt.val2 || 0)', function(total) {
  $scope.cnt.val3 = total;
});
```

This way val3 is updated when val1 or val2 change, but also editable on its own.

Comment: @RameshRajendran sorry what is not working exactly? If you clear who, val3 or val1/val2? I didn't check for when a value is empty indeed, I have edited my answer with that.